# Show document sets in document library webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

In a document library webpart I'd like to see all documents and all document sets but not folders and not the files inside the document sets. (How) is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could show all documents and all document sets without folders. You can also hide documents in document sets.

1.Create a column named test. Fill in the test column of all documents in document sets with the value 1.

2.Go to library settings -> Select the view -> Set filter.
[image]